# Define cell where xlsxwriter start writing

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

i have to fill a xlsx file with content using xlsx writer.

I collect data with pandas from an existing xlsx file and create the dataset "dataset_dn_1" (all NaN will be filled with the string from 'empty' :

```
data = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=2)
dataset_s1_dn = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['dn'])
dataset_s1_dn['dn'] = dataset_s1_dn['dn'].fillna(empty)
```

that works fine.
After this I write the column to a record and make a list out of it (I have to use a list because I don't want to override the whole content in the destination file because of formatting):

```
rec_1 = dataset_s1_dn.to_records(index=False)
list_1 = list(rec_1)
```

Works also good.

Now I want to write the column to the destination file with the following loop:

```
for row, line in enumerate(list_1):
    for col, cell in enumerate(line):
        worksheet1.write(row, col, cell)
```

That works, but i want to start writing at cell A4 not A1.
I tried the following but get an error:

```
worksheet1.write('A4', row, col, cell)
worksheet1.write(0, 3, row, col, cell)
```

both not working.

The error message:

```
TypeError: _write_number() takes from 4 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That works, but i want to start writing at cell A4 not A1.

Something like this should probably work:

```
for row, line in enumerate(list_1):
    for col, cell in enumerate(line):
        worksheet1.write(row + 3, col, cell)
```

Comment: yes that works fine! i found this at the moment for my self and want to answer my own answer and than i saw your post! :D but thank you anyway.